# Insert query operator on yii2 active field?

Tags: yii2, active-form

i was wondering, can i use activefield to insert operator for query andwhere? 
like this image below

Example 1

[image: Example 1]

Example 2

[image: Example 2]

EDIT 1:
Notice that each row contain 3 column. what i want to achieve is to insert column 2 into the form so the user can choose how he/she want to search by operator. can i use this with activefield? or should customize it myself?

EDIT 2:
My question is, can i do this with http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html ?

Comment: Don't get it. What you want to achieve? Provide more details and example.

Comment: So you want to implement operator switch for some fields?

Comment: yes sir how can i do that?

Comment: Sorry mate, I read this 3 times, I understand what you want to do but I do not understand the question.